# Using the WordPress selected() function

Tags: forms

I'm using the WordPress `selected()` function to display the current option in a dropdown list. The issue I am having is that for some reason WordPress is printing out `selected='selected'` above the form in addition to in the actual `<option>` elements. This is how I am using the `selected()` function.

```
<select name='gender'>
<option value='male' " . selected( $values['gender'] , 'male') . ">Male</option>
<option value='female' " . selected( $values['gender'] , 'female') . ">Female</option>
<option value='other' " . selected( $values['gender'] , 'other') . ">Other</option>         
</select>
```

Removing the markup above eliminates the `selected='selected'`which is appearing completely outside of the `<form>` element.

Answer (score 7):

The selected function causes immediate output, it does not return a string. Therefore you can't use it like that, in a string building mode.

If you want it to return a string instead of immediately outputting the text, pass false to the $echo parameter.

```
$string = "
<select name='gender'>
<option value='male' " . selected( $values['gender'] , 'male', false) . ">Male</option>
<option value='female' " . selected( $values['gender'] , 'female', false) . ">Female</option>
<option value='other' " . selected( $values['gender'] , 'other', false) . ">Other</option>         
</select>
";
```

Comment: nails it, on the correct assumption that the form markup was part of a constructed string.

Comment: Thank you! I had been looking at the Codex page (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected) which makes no reference to that last parameter.

Comment: **FYI:** The selected() function returns a value preceeded by a space, so there's no need to add additional space before the function call.

Answer (score 1):

Where are your PHP tags?

```
<select name="gender">
<option value="male" <?php selected( $values['gender'] , 'male'); ?>>Male</option>
<option value="female" <?php selected( $values['gender'] , 'female'); ?>>Female</option>
<option value="other" <?php selected( $values['gender'] , 'other'); ?>>Other</option>         
</select>
```

Unless you're somehow wrapping the whole thing in an echo that isn't displayed in your code snippet?

Also, probably entirely a matter of personal preference, but I always put HTML attributes in double-quotes, and PHP attributes in single quotes, in order to help avoid mixing them up in mixed PHP/HTML markup.

Comment: The whole statement is wrapped in double quotes and returned from a method that displays the form when called. The quotes are they way they are because I reversed them from my normal method on the off chance that it would make a difference. It did not.